# How to recognise Longest Alphabetic word in an array of strings in Java? (any substring without symbols or numbers)

Tags: java, arrays, string, character

I am new to Java and I need to solve an exercise that requires the following:

For a string that the user inputs, return the largest word (so far so good here)

But, it should take into account that numbers and symbols are not words.

For example: `Hello, my name is Jonathan and my phone is 0123456789` should return `"Jonathan"` as longest word.

Example 2: `H3llo W0rld, Java 1s fun!`, should return `"Java"` as longest word.

In my pseudo-code I thought about the following:
A) Request input from user.

B) While input invalid, loop.

C) Scan the input

D) Separate the words by the spaces, or tokens.

E) If Word contains just letters A-Z && a-z do the following code:

e1) Check for longest word, with a for.

e2) Print result

F) else if: move to the next word.

Here is the code that I have so far. As you see, many parts are taken from here and adapted to the code. The "Find the longest in array" is a popular subject, yet I am not able to do the checking for the alphabetical characters.
Any help will be welcomed.

The problem is that I don't know how to implement the part that checks for letters.

Code:

```
package longestword;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LongestWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a String: ");

        //looping for non empty strings
        int largestLength = 0;
        String largestWord = "";
        String userinput = sc.nextLine();
        while (userinput.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Please insert a String: ");
            userinput = sc.nextLine();
        }

        for (String b : userinput.split(" ")) {
            if (largestWord.length() == 0) {
                largestLength = b.length();
                largestWord = b;
            } else if (b.length() >= largestLength) {
                largestLength = b.length();
                largestWord = b;
            }
        }
        sc.close();
        System.out.println("Longest Word: " + largestWord);

    }

    public boolean isAlpha(String userinput) {
        char[] chars = userinput.toCharArray();

        for (char c : chars) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(c)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
/*

     char c = '*';

        if( (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))
            System.out.println(c + " is an alphabet.");
        else
            System.out.println(c + " is not an alphabet.");
    }
}
*/
```

Comment: Why don'y you use your `isAlpha` method?

Comment: I am trying to, just didn't know how to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `isAlpha` method to `static` and use it as follows:

```
for (String b : userinput.split(" ")) {
    if (isAlpha(b)) {
        if (largestWord.length() == 0) {
            largestLength = b.length();
            largestWord = b;
        } else if (b.length() >= largestLength) {
            largestLength = b.length();
            largestWord = b;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just need to look for how to convert it to Static, but that shouldn't be a problem. Thanks Eran for your help! Really appreciate it :).

Comment: @jonakru that's simple - `public static boolean isAlpha(String userinput) {}...`

Comment: Thanks Eran for all. What I was needing was the implementation of the IsAlpha. Right now the code doesn't work properly, for a string :"asdasd asd4a65sd4a6s5d4a6sd a6s5d4a6s5d4a ssddaasssddddddddd I got 3 lines of Longest Word: asdasd and then the correct answer. It is on me to correct it. Thanks for the help provided!

Comment: @jonakru strange - I tried that input and got just "Longest Word: ssddaasssddddddddd"

Comment: Found the mistake, I had misplaced a "}", that was including the System.out.println. So, for every word check it was printing the longest word so far. Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

A possibly easier approach could be to split the string by any non-letter character, and let Java's streams do the heavy lifting for you:

```
String longestWorld =
    Arrays.stream(userInput.split("[^a-zA-z]"))
          .max(Comparator.comparing(String::length).reversed())
          .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are probably right about that. It happens that right now I am at the beginning of the course, so it is expected from us to use For, While, Loops, more basic stuff.